# Pagination in Flask does not work

Tags: python, pagination, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a view:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index/<int:page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(page=1):
    posts = Post.query.paginate(page, 3, False).items
    return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)
```

Code template:

```
    {% if posts %}
    <ol>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <li>{{ post.title }}</li>  | {{ post.text }} | {{ post.time }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    {% else %}
    <h2>There is no posts</h2>
    {% endif %}

    {% if posts.has_prev %}<a href="{{ url_for('index', page=posts.prev_num) }}"><< Newer posts</a>{% else %}<< Newer posts{% endif %} |
    {% if posts.has_next %}<a href="{{ url_for('index', page=posts.next_num) }}">Older posts >></a>{% else %}Older posts >>{% endif %}
```

The problem is that it does not generate me a link to see more posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.has_prev` and `.has_next` are attributes of the [`Pagination` instance](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.Pagination), but you are discarding that instance. All you passed into the view is the `Pagination.items` attribute. You are then trying to still access the `.has_prev` and `.has_next` attributes on the items list, and those attributes do not exist there so Jinja2 resolves those as *undefined*.

Pass in the `Pagination` instance:

```
posts = Post.query.paginate(page, 3, False)
return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)
```

and adjust your template:

```html
{% if posts.items %}
    <ol>
    {% for post in posts.items %}
        <li>{{ post.title }}</li>  | {{ post.text }} | {{ post.time }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
{% else %}
    <h2>There is no posts</h2>
{% endif %}

{% if posts.has_prev %}<a href="{{ url_for('index', page=posts.prev_num) }}"><< Newer posts</a>{% else %}<< Newer posts{% endif %} |
{% if posts.has_next %}<a href="{{ url_for('index', page=posts.next_num) }}">Older posts >></a>{% else %}Older posts >>{% endif %}
```